# Self-study: Which option is NOT a prediction of the central limit theorem?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

"All of the following are predictions of the Central Limit Theorem except:

1) The sample mean distribution will be approximately normally distributed if the sample size is large

2) The mean of the distribution of the sample mean will be equal to the population mean.

3) The variance of the distribution of the sample mean will be equal to the population variance divided by the sample size.

4) The standard deviation of the sample mean will grow as the sample increases."

***My reasoning:***

1) is correct, as I increase the sample size more and more, the sample mean distribution will tend to be more normally distributed.

4) cannot be right.  The standard deviation of the sample mean formula is:  population std. dev / sqrt(sample size). So if I increase the denominator, the value will decrease.

That leaves that 2) and 3) must be right, but I don't know how to justify that.  Would someone please explain me?

Comment: If the data are a random sample of size $n$ from a population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$ then (2) says $E(\bar X_n) = \mu$ and (3) says $Var(\bar X_n) = \sigma^2/n,$ both of which are results that you should find stated, if not proved, in your text or class notes. The subscript $n$ in the notation $\bar X_n$ indicates that the sample mean is based on a sample of size $n.$

Comment: Why is 1) correct?

Comment: You state that "4) cannot be right."  How, then, could that possibly be a prediction of the CLT?